# Extract all occurrences of a pattern using regular expression and php

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract all the word that occurs between `'ob'` and `','`, i.e., 
from the string

> `' QS=TCE,Ob=Web technology,OB=Product SPe,OB=Dev profile,OB=Computer Management,oB=Hardware Services,cd=sti,CD=com,cd=ws'`

I want the following results:

> `Web technology,Product SPe,Dev profile,Computer Management,Hardware Services`

What I tried is this:

```
preg_match_all("!\OB=(\w+)\,!", ' QS=TCE,Ob=Web technology,OB=Product SPe,OB=Dev profile,OB=Computer Management,oB=Hardware Services,cd=sti,CD=com,cd=ws', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

But it does not give any result. What is wrong in this?

Comment: try removing the `\ `'s

Comment: $matches= preg_split(" pattern ", ' QS=TCE,Ob=Web technology,OB=Product SPe,OB=Dev profile,OB=Computer Management,oB=Hardware Services,cd=sti,CD=com,cd=ws'); 


Please try with  preg_split()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to account for whitespace between your words, I would use negation here. Also you need to remove the escape sequences preceding the "O" and comma and turn on the `i` (case-insensitive) mode modifier.

```
preg_match_all('!OB=([^,]+),!i', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/223908)